# Update Function Input With Dropdown

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to use the output from two dropdown selections to change the data that I am querying in a data gathering function. I can't quite figure out the proper structure for this. In this example I get the following error: `KeyError: 'outputs_list'`

**How do I structure the callback in a way that stores the selection in a variable within the function?**

```
app.layout = html.Div(
html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='event-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': '2021 test', 'value': '12345'},
            {'label': '2021 test 2', 'value': '78901'},
        ],
        value = '1',
        searchable=False,
        style={"width": "40%", "padding-left": "75px", "padding-top": "5px","padding-bottom": "5px","text-align": "center"}
    ),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='run-dropdown',
        options=[
            {'label': 'Practice 1', 'value': 'Practice 1'},
            {'label': 'Practice 2', 'value': 'Practice 2'},
        ],
        value = 'Practice 1',
        searchable=False,
        style={"width": "40%", "padding-left": "75px", "padding-top": "5px","padding-bottom": "5px","text-align": "center"}
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id='lapTime-graph',style={'width': '100%', 'height': '900px'}),
    dcc.Interval(
        id='interval-component',
        interval=1*5000, # in milliseconds
        n_intervals=0
    ),
    html.Div(id='output1')
])
)

@app.callback(Output('output1', 'children'),
              [Input('event-dropdown', 'value'),
               Input('run-dropdown', 'value')])
def query_data(run_value, event_value):
    Run = run_value
    Event = event_value
    global D
    global tab
    global color_box
    global Lap
    global color_tab
    global text

    ----Update data in query based on drop down selections----

    print("query_init")
    return D, tab, color_box, Lap, color_tab, text
```

Comment: Nowhere in this snippet do we see the word "outputs_list".  Where does that error occur?  And aren't your parameter names in the wrong order?

Comment: @TimRoberts `Key Error: outputs_list` is the key error I get when calling the function `query_data()` The error is directly related to how the callback is setup. I just can't find enough information to understand what is incorrect